# command line interface for struts2 spring framework (compiled by maven)

Tags: java, spring, command-line, struts2

I currently have a project that is a web application (struts2 + spring) that is compiled with maven, running on a tomcat7 server on CentOS6.3.

I am wondering if there is any way to provide also a command line interface to, for example dump out the content of some spring beans, or other functions that interacts with the system. This CLI is supposed to be run on the CentOS server itself.  Because currently, all interaction with the application can only be done through the browser on other client machines.  I wonder if any possibility I can create a command line program for the application's administrator.  For some reason I do not think there are much online resource regarding this aspect.

Comment: Take a look at JMX: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JMX. Spring has facilities to work with it too. After that you just need a CLI application that connects to the JMX exposed by your web app and calls the methods defined in your backend, these methods would do what you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is adding some JMX capabilities to your web application.

Since you are already using Spring, you can use the JMX facilities offered by Spring, you will find the documentation with some samples on the officiel [Spring JMX documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jmx.html), and you can find on the web a [JMX Hello World](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/source-code-java-jmx-hello-world-application) that could be of some help for you to understand what's going on.

Then you can use something like [jmxsh](https://code.google.com/p/jmxsh/) or even code your own.